# Service provider Spring WS verifying SAML assertion from WSO2

Tags: java, cxf, spring-ws, ws-security, wso2-identity-server

How web service provider say, 3rd party Service provider like Spring WS authenticate or validate the SAML Assertion received from client in case of WSO2 as identity provider. Please suggest any examples for such custom implementation

Thanks

Comment: Any one aware of such scenario, please reply, its extremely urgent for me

Comment: me also need same solution